# Please help me identify connector

Tags: connector

Please help me to identify this connectors. They seems look like banana connector, but they are smaller (2 mm inside).

[image: connector]
[image: connector]

Comment: looks like a 2mm banana to me

Answer (score 1):

They're called "[pin connectors](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-wire-pin-connectors/1442847?k=0.080%20pin%20connector)", and the diameter is actually 0.080" (2.03 mm).

Comment: While I've seen pin connectors before I've never seen inline receptacles for them. Not that I'm particularly doubting the answer but where / how would you find the receptacles as above?